# Index indefinido datatable

Tags: php, datatables

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de crear un buscador que al insertar el valor de un año y mes me cargue un datatable con todos los datos almacenados en base de datos el pase de datos lo realizo a traves de ajax a php de esta manera

```
 $(document).on("click", "#buscar", function () {
 var meses = $("#meses").val();
 var year = $("#year").val();
 $('#lisForm').dataTable({ 
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"bDestroy": true,
"bJQueryUI": true,
"ajax": {
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': 'reportes_formato/bus_mes_year',
    'data': {
       meses: meses,
       year: year,

    }
}
 });
});
```

y la obtengo en php de la siguiente manera

```
public function bus_mes_year(){
     $meses = $_POST['meses'];
     $year = $_POST['year'];

      $table = "fn_bus_mes_year($meses, $year)";
      $primaryKey = 'id_for';

    $columns = array(
        array('db' => 'id_for', 'dt' => 0),
        array('db' => 'item', 'dt' => 2),
        array('db' => 'tipo', 'dt' => 3),
        array('db' => 'titulo', 'dt' => 4),
        array('db' => 'codigo', 'dt' => 5),
        array('db' => 'uni_adm','dt' => 6),           
        array('db' => 'fec_rec_int', 'dt' => 7),
        array('db' => 'num_for_apr','dt' => 8),
        array('db' => 'tiempo_asig_act', 'dt' => 9),           
    );

    //Condiciones adicionales para el WHERE
    $filtroAdd = " id_for  <> 0 "; // 

    //Parámetros de conexión
    $pg_details = array('user' => USUDB, 'pass' => CLADB, 'db' => NOMDB, 'host' => SERDB);
    echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple($_GET, $pg_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $filtroAdd));

    //print trim($cedula);die;

   $result =$this->reportes_model->bus_mes_year($meses, $year);
        print_r($result);die;
        if ($result == NULL){
            $mensaje="No hay registros guardados intente con otra fecha";
            print_r(json_encode($mensaje));
        }else{
        print json_encode($result);
        }

}
```

Mi problema es que al momento de realizar la búsqueda me sale el siguiente mensaje de error el cual no le e podido encontrar solución

Message: Undefined index: columns
Message: Undefined index: draw

Comment: ¿Los datos están llegando al servidor? ¿Depuraste en consola lo que estás recibiendo realmente?

Comment: Si los datos llegan buscando en internet logre cambiar esta linea SSP::simple($_GET, $pg_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $filtroAdd)); por $_POST y me muestra por consola los resultados mas sin embargo sigue sin mostrarme nada en datatable